# No url access to oracle apex page

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm working with Oracle APEX 19.2 and trying to prevent user from entering directly from the URL to specific page.
I set the "Page Access Protection" to "No URL access".
According to help

> No URL Access
>   The page may not be accessed using a URL.
>   However, the page may be the target of a Branch to Page branch type, as this does not perform a URL redirect.

On different page I created a button that should be access for this page.
When I'm trying to create a Branch there is no "Branch to Page" I tried "Page or URL (Redirect"), "Page (Show only)","Function returning a Page (Show only)" but I always get error:

> This page cannot be invoked using a URL or using a GET or POST to the show procedure, it must be called using a "Branch to Page" branch type.

How can I access a page with "No URL access"?

Comment: Assume Page 2 is the page with "No URL access" and Page 1 is the page where you have button. Now, branch with type "Page (Show only)" works as long as Page 1 "Page Properties > Advanced > Reload on Submit" is set to "Always". I have checked this on in APEX 18.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application security attribute called "Deep Linking". That setting determines whether a user can access an url directly or is sent to the homepage. You can set it in `Application Properties > Security > Deep Linking`.